# Please troubleshoot this full-wave rectifier circuit using op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, control, rectifier

I am designing a full-wave rectifier using op-amps, which need to rectify a signal between 0 and 10 V, to a voltage between 5 and 10 V.

[image: This is the circuit I designed]

The circuit works properly when the input voltage is between 0 and 5 V. That is:

Input -> Output
5 V -> 5 V
4 V -> 6 V
3 V -> 7 V
2 V -> 8 V
1 V -> 9 V
0 V -> 10 V

But when the input is between 5 V and 10 V, it works properly for the first few volts but then the voltage drops off, as if there is a voltage drop somewhere:

Input -> Output
6 V -> 6 V
7 V -> 7 V
8 V -> 8 V
9 V -> 7.8 V
10 V -> 6.86 V

Can anybody tell me how I can solve it, or what the issue is?

The desired result would be:
Input -> Output
6 V -> 6 V
7 V -> 7 V
8 V -> 8 V
9 V -> 9 V
10 V -> 10 V

By the way, I know it's not in the the schematic, but the LM324 is being powered from a single rail supply of 12 V.

Comment: Monitor what's going on around pin 8. And explore what it takes to get the LM324 to drive close to its supply rails : should be some info in the datasheet. Or try a better op amp.

Comment: So @BrianDrummond , are you suggesting that the op-amp is saturating at 9V, altough being powered from 12V ?

Comment: @BrianDrummond you are right the opamp is going to the Vsat^- at 9V and 10V. So what can I do to solve this issue given that I cannot change my supply configuration ? Thanks for the help

Comment: You have an additional issue...your diodes aren't ideal.  Even if you can get a rail-to-rail op amp, the output from your first op amp would have to go to -0.7V to drive the rectified node to 0V.

Comment: U3C must be saturating trying to go to -0.7.  can You reduce the gain in U3B under unity then increase the gain in U3A ? Or need help?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 can you please help me decrease the gain of U3C please ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the limitations of output swing , it is possible to barely fit 10Vpp rectified to 5 to 10V with > 10k load on the output stage.  The diode cause the 5Vp positive swing to be inverted towards -0.7 which clips the signal in the 1st stage.  The 2nd stage inverts again with a gain of 2 but the BJT output with a high side Darlington and current source that drops from V+ by 2 to 3 V based on load from 10k to 2K.

The low side Vol is pretty close to 0V with a single Vce(sat) driver.

The solution is to cut positive swing gain then boost it for 2nd stage. This is easily done by reducing R11,R12 by the same % such as 50%. Then unity gain is restored.  R11 cuts stage 1 gain then R12 restores the gain in stage 2 only for positive input swing.

Bonus

If you wanted to eliminate the 5V offset a resistor from 12V to U3-2 of 2.4k will reduce to x mV offset, resulting in 0 to 5V output.  Other ways can achieve the same result.

Since the open loop gain is 1.5e4 the diode voltage error is reduced by 1.5e4, which is the “large signal gain”.

Answer (score 0):

Go for a **rail to rail opamp** like this [one](http://www.ti.com/product/OPA4705).
 The linked part may not be the best but make sure it fits in all aspects to your application.

The electrical characteristics will show you Bout output voltage swing.. the part you have chosen can go upto 26V when the supply is around 30 V. A rail to rail opamp is the best solution because you have no option to change the power supply.

For the part in the question:.

[image]